# Upgrading PHP 5.4.0 in XAMPP for Windows?

Tags: php, windows, xampp, installation

I want to upgrade to PHP 5.4.0 in XAMPP. I'm using windows operating system. I searched on web, but there was no proper guide for this as it was released recently.

Can anyone give me some instructions on how to upgrade to PHP 5.4.0 in XAMPP (windows)?

Answer (score 5):

1. [Download the latest binary version of PHP](http://windows.php.net/download/) (make sure to get the .zip package not the installer)
2. De-archive it to a directory
3. Copy the contents of the directory in the php subfolder of your XAMPP installation directory, overwriting the files which are already present
4. Overwrite the files which are already present in the apache\bin directory with the newer versions.
5. Now the trick: take the files which have a "_2" in their names (for example php5apache2_2.dll or php5apache2_2_filter.dll), copy them in the apache\bin subdirectory and remove the "_2" part, overwriting the existing files. This is necessary because by XAMPP uses Apache version 2.2 and the files with the 2 prefix are built for Apache 2.0, so you must take the files build for the newer version (which has a different plugin interface) and rename them in the filenames XAMPP expects.

[Source](http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2007/07/updating-php-in-xampp-for-windows.html)

Comment: I try the instruction. but when i start apache lot of popup warnings displayed. some of that warning message telling php5.dll not found and lot of other dll not found alerts also displayed.

Comment: did you rename the files like step 5 suggests?

Answer (score 3):

I found a working php_uploadprogress.dll extension for xampp windows with php 5.4 here:

http://www.fsbcomputers.com/php_uploadprogress

there are 32 and 64 bit versions as well as a preview for php 5.5.

By the way, the php build numbers, apache /xampp refers to are:

PHP 5.2: 20060613
PHP 5.3: 20090626
PHP 5.4: 20100525

Answer (score 2):

I hope that you are still following this, I installed php 5.4 on the latest xampp stable with no problem.
Fortunately for you, there is a beta update of xampp which makes life easier. http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-beta.html

Just make sure to make a complete backup of your old xampp directory, and export your old databases so you can import them into your new (updated) mysql installation. Alternatively you do not need to update mysql, I use this beta and I can say that it's pretty solid.

EDIT: The pop-up warning were a problem that I had too, I recommend using the latest beta. But, you can fix the errors and use php 5.4 on your old install (not recommended) by commenting out the following line in php.ini

```
extension=php_oci8.dll
```

Change to

```
;extension=php_oci8.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done the upgrade in ubuntu. Following are the steps to do the upgrade.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: This is for ubuntu. But I need it for windows.